# Where to locate thermometer in my Weber charcoal grill

Tags: grilling, barbecue

I am about to purchase a Weber charcoal grill. For optimal cooking, I want to be able to monitor and control the temperature surrounding my meat by operating the vents.

What is the best way to do this? Where should I place my thermometer and what kind of thermometer do you recommend for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Per [Amazing Ribs Thermometer Buying Guide](https://www.amazingribs.com/ratings-reviews/thermometers/):

The best method is a probe thermometer.  Position  the tip of the probe  at the level where the food rests, about 1 inch above the grate or rack, and one inch from the food.  You don't want it closer because of the cooling effect of the food itself.

You can suspend the probe above the grate with a clip if it comes with one.  Otherwise, make a ball of aluminum foil, and simply poke the probe through it for an improvised offset stand.

[image: Improvised stand from Amazing Ribs]
<sub>(source: [amazingribs.com](https://www.amazingribs.com/images/accessories/probe_holder_foil.jpg))</sub>

Picture from Amazing ribs article linked above

---

Note:  the referenced article is very long, and a wealth of detailed information.  Search the page for the headline "I'll tell you where to stick it" (about half way down the page) and start reading there (okay, read the whole thing, but that is the section that is directly applicable to your question.)

Comment: Following up on this. Do you think it is very important to have a wireless thermometers for charcoal grills? I am thinking both for the meat probe and grill thermometer. I am worried about the wire will leave an opening on the lid

Comment: No, I don't think wireless is important; it is a convenience so you can see the temperature from inside your house if you are doing a long-smoking item (some can take 12 hours or more).  Webers are not paragons of insulation in any case, and the lead wire is very thin.